# Choose a file starting with a given string

Tags: python, file

In a directory I have a lot of files, named more or less like this:

```
001_MN_DX_1_M_32
001_MN_SX_1_M_33
012_BC_2_F_23
...
...
```

In Python, I have to write a code that selects from the directory a file starting with a certain string. For example, if the string is `001_MN_DX`, Python selects the first file, and so on.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try using `os.listdir`,`os.path.join` and `os.path.isfile`.
In long form (with for loops),

```
import os
path = 'C:/'
files = []
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and '001_MN_DX' in i:
        files.append(i)
```

Code, with list-comprehensions is

```
import os
path = 'C:/'
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
         '001_MN_DX' in i]
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15313024/2) for the long explanation...

Comment: I would replace `and '001_MN_DX' in i` to `and i.startswith('001_MN_DX')`
Since a file 'E_001_MN_DX.txt' would match as well the original code.

Answer (score 96):

```
import os
prefixed = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.startswith("prefix")]
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use the module **glob**, it follows the Unix shell rules for pattern matching.
[See more.](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/glob.html)

```
from glob import glob

files = glob('*001_MN_DX*')
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import os, re
for f in os.listdir('.'):
   if re.match('001_MN_DX', f):
       print f
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the os module to list the files in a directory.

Eg: Find all files in the current directory where name starts with 001_MN_DX

```
import os
list_of_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) #list of files in the current directory
for each_file in list_of_files:
    if each_file.startswith('001_MN_DX'):  #since its all type str you can simply use startswith
        print each_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
 for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.startswith('criteria here'):
        print filename #print the name of the file to make sure it is what 
                               you really want. If it's not, review your criteria
                #Do stuff with that file
```

Answer (score 1):

with newer `pathlib` module, see [link](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/#reading-and-writing-files):

```
from pathlib import Path
myDir = Path('my_directory/')

fileNames = [file.name for file in myDir.iterdir() if file.name.startswith('prefix')]    
filePaths = [file for file in myDir.iterdir() if file.name.startswith('prefix')]
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python3 you can use [**`pathlib.Path`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) as follows:

```py
Path(root_dir).glob('*001_MN_DX*')
```

And if you need recursive globbing in subdirs:

```py
Path(root_dir).glob('**/*001_MN_DX*')
```