# Extract image position from .docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to get the image index from the .docx file using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. I'm able to extract the name of the image, image height and width. But not the index where it is in the word file

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document(filename)
for s in doc.inline_shapes:
    print (s.height.cm,s.width.cm,s._inline.graphic.graphicData.pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.name)
```

output

```
21.228  15.920 IMG_20160910_220903848.jpg
```

In fact I would like to know if there is any simpler way to get the image name , like *s.height.cm* fetched me the height in cm. My primary requirement is to get to know where the image is in the document, because I need to extract the image and do some work on it and then again put the image back to the same location

Comment: you could do this pretty easily using win32com which supports the full MS Word Object Model. The python-docx library seems especially limited, and moreso when it comes to working with or accessing Shape objects. Also, the `InlineShapes` sequence supports indexed access ([read the dox](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape.html#docx.shape.InlineShapes)) so while the `s` doesn't have an `index` property, you can treat them as an indexed sequence.

Comment: @DavidZemens could you please elaborate on the indexed sequence concept?

Comment: That means that the `inline_shapes` sequence is ordered and can be accessed by index e.g., `doc.inline_shapes[0]`, etc., no?  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Ok. I get it. But my initial question was something different. Suppose the content of the .docx file is : **this is an example document <image>. the image is located before this statement.** so what I need is the index or location where <image> is present, in this case its after **document** and before **.the image**

Comment: Reviewing the dox for that library, does not seem to be supported. Use win32com to instantiate the word document with all of the Word Object Model methods/properties, an inline shape should have a `.range` (or `.Range`, not sure on capitalization) property that will identify the *character* position within the document.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This operation is not directly supported by the API.

However, if you're willing to dig into the internals a bit and use the underlying `lxml` API it's possible.

The general approach would be to access the `ImagePart` instance corresponding to the picture you want to inspect and modify, then read and write the `._blob` attribute (which holds the image file as bytes).

This specimen XML might be helpful:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/shapes/picture.html#specimen-xml

From the inline shape containing the picture, you get the `<a:blip>` element with this:

```
blip = inline_shape._inline.graphic.graphicData.pic.blipFill.blip
```

The relationship id (r:id generally, but r:embed in this case) is available at:

```
rId = blip.embed
```

Then you can get the image part from the document part

```
document_part = document.part
image_part = document_part.related_parts[rId]
```

And then the binary image is available for read and write on `._blob`.

If you write a new blob, it will replace the prior image when saved.

You probably want to get it working with a single image and get a feel for it before scaling up to multiple images in a single document.

There might be one or two image characteristics that are cached, so you might not get all the finer points working until you save and reload the file, so just be alert for that.

Not for the faint of heart as you can see, but should work if you want it bad enough and can trace through the code a bit :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also inspect paragraphs with a simple loop, and check which xml contains an image (for example if an xml contains "graphicData"), that is which is an image container (you can do the same with runs):

```
from docx import Document

image_paragraphs = []
doc = Document(path_to_docx)
for par in doc.paragraphs:
    if 'graphicData' in par._p.xml:
        image_paragraphs.append(par)
```

Than you unzip docx file, images are in the "images" folder, and they are in the same order as they will be in the image_paragraphs list. On every paragraph element you have many options how to change it. If you want to extract img process it and than insert it in the same place, than

```
paragraph.clear()
paragraph.add_run('your description, if needed')
run = paragraph.runs[0]
run.add_picture(path_to_pic, width, height)
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. However you must count the number of occurrences of the tag `graphicData` inside the paragraph, because there can be more than one (if using string.count() you must halve result by 2 due to opening and closing tags).

Comment: I unziped the docx, and images have extensions: `.png`, `.jpg` or `.htm` (`.htm` is actually for PNG images). Any idea of how to get the name, with extension ? (Without resorting to using module `os` like in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312953/choose-a-file-starting-with-a-given-string) ?)

Answer (score 3):

So, I've never really written any answers here, but i think this might be the solution to your problem. With this little code you can see the position of your images given all the paragraphs. Hope it helps.

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(filename)

paraGr = []             
index = []

par = doc.paragraphs
for i in range(len(par)):
     paraGr.append(par[i].text)
     if 'graphicData' in par[i]._p.xml:
         index.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3

```
pip install python-docx

import docx
doc = docx.Document(document_path)
P = []
I = []
par = doc.paragraphs
for i in range(len(par)):
     P.append(par[i].text)
     if 'graphicData' in par[i]._p.xml:
         I.append(i)
print(I)
```

#returns list of index(Image_Reference)