# Python - How do you read multiple files in a folder starting by xyz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying at the moment to read several files (and save them as objects) starting by "valeurs..." in a directory.
I've got 4 of these in the directory. Anyways i ran this code:

```
directory = 'C:/Users/thoma/Downloads/mini_projet_4/mini_projet_4/'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        testing = read_csv(nom_fichier = filename, separateur = "|")
        continue
    continue
```

However, this code only reads the last .txt file out of the 4. Could anyone help me please. (I did search but to no avail)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose a file starting with a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312953/choose-a-file-starting-with-a-given-string). BTW, you keep overriding `testing` in your loop, so if you access the variable after the loop, it will always have the content of the last file.

Comment: `if filename.startswith('xyz') and filename.endswith('.txt')`? Also, you have too many `continue` statements.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Thanks however the code you mentionned from that thread doesn't work. I am actually trying to make the code work with the custom function read_csv I've got. Do you have any tips to read all the *.txt file in the folder ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is what [globing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) is for:

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path('C:/Users/thoma/Downloads/mini_projet_4/mini_projet_4/')
xyz_files = directory.glob('xyz*.txt')

for file in xyz_files:
    print(f)
```

See the documentation on [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

ok I managed to do it by tweaking a bit my code:

```
random_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        random_list.append(read_csv(filename, "|"))
        continue
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears as if your loop will only give you the last instance of your .txt files. Each time your For loop iterates, it replaces the `testing` variable with a new instance of `read_csv()`.

It might be simpler/easier to open a file, run your operations against it and close it before moving on.